# Variable changes without me using it

Tags: java

I have a problem, my variable tabOffrandes change without I change this so I don't understand. This is my code:

```java
 public static int[] tri_selection(int[] tab) {
        int a;
        for (int i = 0; i < tab.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < tab.length; j++) {
                if (tab[i] > tab[j]){
                    a = tab[j];
                    tab[j] = tab[i];
                    tab[i] = a;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
        return tab;
    }

    public static Joueur[] offrande(int[] offrandes) {

        int[] tabOffrandes = offrandes;

        printTab(tabOffrandes);
        int[] ordreOffrande = tri_selection(offrandes);
        printTab(tabOffrandes);
```

The terminal respond:

```java
8 - 3 - 5 - 1
1 - 3 - 5 - 8
```

The function printTab just print all of the numbers in int[], I think it's not very important to show this.

Comment: You're for sure using the array that `tabOffrandes` refers to when calling `tri_selection(offrandes)`. The parameter `tab` refers to the same array as `tabOffrandes` in that case.

Comment: Yoy have just assigned the reference of `offrandes` to `offrandes`, so basically they are one and the same. However now if you change elements in one array, it would get reflected on other too.

Comment: `tabOffrandes`, `offrandes` and `ordreOffrande` all point to the same object. Change one (as you do inside `tri_selection`), change them all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that you refer to the same array in the memory, even if you provide different names for them.

This is only an assumption, but what I think you are trying to do by writing:

```
int[] tabOffrandes = offrandes;
```

is to create a copy of your original array, right?

To achieve this, you must write the code as:

```
int[] tabOffrandes = Arrays.copyOf(offrandes, offrandes.length);
```

This way, your original `offrandes` array will not be affected when you call the `tri_selection` function.

---

Not related to your question, but it might help you in the future. I'm not sure what's your implementation for `printTab` function. I assume that you manually iterate through the array and print the items? Just wanted to let you know that there is a shorter solution, by using `Arrays.toString(...)`, in case you didn't know:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tabOffrandes));
```

Comment: Ok thank you, it's good now and thank you for the another tips.